# What is the difference between an adjective before the noun and after the noun?

Tags: adjectives, modifiers, postpositive-adjectives

For a long time I'm having trouble understanding the difference between two kind of expressions like those below in terms of meaning, not grammar:

> 1. **Excited people** are looking forward to seeing this event.
> 2. **People excited** are looking forward to seeing this event.

EDITED TO USE CLEARER EXAMPLES:

> 3. "All **navigable rivers** are being patrolled."
> 4. "All **rivers navigable** are being patrolled."

As a native speaker, how do these expressions in bold sound to you? Is there any difference in meaning between examples #3 and #4? If so what is it, and why is this so?

Comment: Consider using better examples. For instance: *"The **concerned people** are looking forward to seeing this event"* versus *"The **people concerned** are looking forward to seeing this event"*.

Comment: Based on the example you gave , what do you think is the answer to my questions above @F.E.

Comment: Better yet, why don't you change your question post to use that specific example (or one like it)? Here's perhaps a more clear cut example: *"All **navigable rivers** are being patrolled"* versus *"All **rivers navigable** are being patrolled"*. In this way, ELL members can write answer posts to answer your question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that grammar is somewhat tied to meaning here. The position of an adjective in a sentence depends on its role.

When used **attributively** (to describe a noun), as stated in other comments and answers, the adjective comes **before** the noun:

> All **navigable rivers** are being patrolled.

If you say:

> All rivers **that are navigable** are being patrolled. (Others are not)

This can become:

> All **rivers navigable** are being patrolled.

At first glance this doesn't really seem to change the meaning since:

rivers that are navigable = navigable rivers

---

Edit: But...

When an adjective comes **after** the noun it describes (like in the 3rd example), it functions as a **postpositive modifier**.  Changing the position of the adjective (relative to the noun it describes) may bring a slight difference in the meaning of the sentence (the meaning of the word itself does not change!). When used *postpositively* an adjective connotes an ephemeral quality, one that is present at the moment, but doesn't always have to be. On the other hand, the adjectives used *attributively* may express either an ephemeral or a permanent characteristic, depending on the context. The difference between attributive and postpositive use of an adjective is explained in more detail in (the middle of) [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53459/nearby-close-by-as-an-adjective-a-preposition-or-an-adverb/53989#53989) and in the comments.

---

Only some adjectives can be used both attributively and postpositively (while retaining the same word meaning), and these are the ones ending in -able and -ible (such as navig**able**). (But not even all of those - see later: responsible).

To cover another aspect (this is where grammar kicks in again): if an adjective is used predicatively (in a pattern: subject + verb + object + complement (here an adjective)) it would be in a sentence like this:

> Signalisation on the banks made **rivers navigable**. (Or something like that, I'm not really an expert on rivers).
>
> The upcoming event made **people excited**.

The meaning of some adjectives (when used as modifiers) changes depending on whether they are used attributively or postpositively. Some examples are: **concerned**, responsible, present etc. Neither navigable nor excited are among those. Here the meaning of the word itself changes and the difference can be determined by checking the dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 2):

In modern English adjectives are put before the noun they qualify.
There are however archaisms where this rule is violated, reminding us of older usage  :

> The Astronomer Royal, a knight errant, God Almighty, the Surgeon General.

And foreign expressions  like

> Persona non grata, spaghetti bolognese.

Since I'm French, let me end with our dangerously irresistible

> Femme fatale

who might lead one to actions later ascribed to

> Force majeure.

Answer (score 1):

In modern English, the adjective should come before the noun it modifies.

> **Excited people** are looking forward to seeing this event.

Comment: I wonder if we could say: People, excited to see this event, were crowding at the entrance?

Comment: You can, but then "excited to see this event" becomes a participle phrase. It still works as an adjective in that it describes the people, but it's not a normal adjective.

Comment: @R Mac You know we can create a sentence like "People who are excited" are looking forward to seeing this event. You know, deletion can be applied to relative clauses.I want to remove "who are" in the sentence , and then the meaning remain the same ,right?

Comment: No, that is not right. When you say, "People who are excited are looking forward to seeing this event," the word "who" is a pronoun and the phrase "are excited" links the adjective "excited" to the pronoun "who" by using the verb "are". If you delete "who are", you completely change the mechanics of the sentence, and with modern English, placing an adjective before the noun it modifies is just the right way to do it. :)

Comment: @RMac "People excited at the opportunity of working for Google should think twice before ....."

Comment: @Araucaria That's still a participle phrase. You should use commas like in the first comment on this thread. In most cases, native English speakers would not be confused by minor mistakes like this (or even by placing an adjective after the noun it modifies), but that's not the correct way to do it.

Comment: This is true a lot of the time. It's very common for adjectives to have **attributive** function, modifying a following noun ("a *red* car"), which is what your answer describes. But adjectives also sometimes have **predicative** function ("The car is *red*."), **postpositive** function ("He left to find the people *responsible*."), or **predeterminer** function ("He had eaten *half* a bar of chocolate.").  If you look up postpositive adjectives, you'll find some relevant information.