# the most common terms day-to-day here

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "The States" is almost never used inside the United States. We just don't say that here.
>
> But Americans will say it overseas because they know people use it that way overseas and it's understandable. They are basically being accommodating. But it's not natural to us here. It's very popular with Canadians, though, and is potentially one way to distinguish them.
>
> I think the most common ***terms day-to-day*** here are "the U.S." and "the United States". "America" is used but primarily in more restricted, poetic, political, patriotic and advertising contexts. That's a lot of opportunity, but it's a more limited set of contexts.

Source: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/how-to-write-the-united-states-of-america-in-other-ways.3931990/#post-20128367

---

1. Is "***day-to-day***" an adjective? If so, why is "***day-to-day***" after the noun "***terms***"?
2. I'd like to know the difference in meaning between "the most common ***terms day-to-day*** here" and "the most common ***day-to-day terms*** here"

Comment: Adjectives can be placed before or after what they modify: [What is the difference between an adjective before the noun and after the noun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/55643/9161)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather informal writing, as its appearance on a web forum suggests.

I would say that

> most common terms day-to-day here are

is an informal use meaning

> ... the most  common terms in everyday use inside the US are ...

and by "day-to-day" the poster means ordinary speech, or everyday use. In those contexts "ordinary" or "everyday" would be adjectives modifying "speech"

The writing here is sufficiently casual if not careless that attempting to analyze the grammatical functions of the individual words is probably wasted effort. It is not a good model for a learner to imitate.

I would add that neither

> the most common terms day-to-day here

nor

> the most common day-to-day terms here

are particularly vcomman usages in my experience, and I think either would sound a bit odd. But I think that the second (day-to-day terms ") is significantly closer to natural than the first is. But I woulksd advise using one of

> - everyday terms
> - terms in everyday use
> - terms in daily use
> - common terms
> - commonly used terms
> - terms in common use

rather than any construct with "day-to-day" to express the meaning here or any similar meaning. As 9it happens, expressing that a word or phrase is or is not in common use is something that happens a lot right here on ELL, and I don't recall seeing any answer or comment using "day-to-day" in this way. It is surely not a common usage here.

---

By the way the statement that

> "The States" is almost never used inside the United States. We just don't say that here.

was not true in the 1950s and 1960s, and perhaps later. This may have been in part due to the influence o returned military people from WWII and the Korean War.

Comment: It's just the opinion of some person on a forum, and easily disproved. '...Issa Rae, who is African American and Senegalese, and her show Insecure had a diasporic feel to it. So yes, I would say it is becoming more visible to those of us **here in the States**.' Belinda Deneen Wallace, University of New Mexico. 'European-Style Christmas Markets Right **Here in the States**' - Afar.com “The Kentucky Air Guard and 123rd are going to be able to use it [the C-130 plane] to its fullest potential **here in the states** or to deploy overseas - U.S. Air Force Vice Chief of Staff Gen. David W. Allvin

Comment: I'd also like to know if "the most common ***terms day-to-day*** here" is natural and has the same meaning as "the most common ***day-to-day terms*** here".

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss  have added a discussion of that to my answeer. I hope it helps