# Is 'only' an adjective and 'off' a preposition in the example sentence?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

In the sentence:

> *He was **only** a yard **off** me.*

I believe 'only' is an adjective because it adds information to the noun 'yard'. 'Off' is a preposition because it relates 'me' to the rest of the sentence.

Am I thinking right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are half right (that would be the second half).

**Only** is used as an [adverb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs) in your sentence. Notice that, if it were used as an adjective to modify the word *yard*, the indefinite article would be in front of the whole phrase, like in this example:

> *He is **an only child.*** (Meaning: he has no siblings.)

If you move the indefinite article, you get an entirely new meaning:

> *He is **only a child.*** (Meaning: Don't yell at him, he is too young to know what he did was wrong)

and in the 2nd example *only* is a [focus adverb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-types). These adverbs precede the word or phrase they modify, to focus attention on it.

It can be argued whether *only* modifies the word *yard* or the whole phrase *a yard off me* in your example but one way or the other it is an adverb that emphasises that the distance was short, that is [not more than](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/only_1) a (or one) yard. For this meaning, dictionaries (such as LDOCE) confirm that *only* is an adverb.

---

As for **off** you are correct, it is a [preposition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/prepositions) as it shows relation in space between the two people *'he'* and *'me'*.

[This post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53459/nearby-close-by-as-an-adjective-a-preposition-or-an-adverb/53989#53989) by F.E. discusses in detail how to determine whether a word is an adjective, an adverb or a preposition.

---

Ref:

- Longman English Grammar (by L.G. Alexander)
- Cambridge Dictionaries Online (English Grammar Today)
- Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English Online