# Near/Nearby, which should i use?

Tags: word-usage

There's been a murder in the scaffolding **nearby** my apartment.

There's been a murder in the scaffolding **near** my apartment.

Are both of them grammatically correct?
Do they mean the same?

Comment: Related: [“nearby” (close by) as an adjective, a preposition, or an adverb](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/53459/3281)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using it as an *adverb*, 'nearby' is okay.

> The clubhouse is *nearby*

But in your examples, you need a preposition and thus, 'near' looks natural.

> There has been a murder in the scaffolding ***<del>nearby</del> near*** my apartment.

Answer (score 0):

Nearby is an adjective, near is an adverb or preposition. You can use both, but the structure would be different.

Prepositional use:

> There has been a murder in the scaffolding near my apartment.

Adjectival use:

> There has been a murder in the nearby scaffolding